# How to Navigate to Screen after GPS been enabled?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

When the User is enabled the GPS I want to navigate it to AuthScreen.js. I'm using react-native-navigation v1 but there is no feature that can navigate just to simple screen, only push and modal but I don't want to use it.

Also using this: react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box

Here are my codes:

```
    componentDidMount() {
this.gpsLocation();
}

gpsLocation = () => {
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
    message: "<h2>Use Location?</h2> \
    This app wants to change your device settings:<br/><br/>\
    Use GPS for location<br/><br/>",
    ok: "Yes",
    cancel: "No",
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#4f6d7a',
      positiveButtonTextColor: '#000000',
      negativeButtonTextColor: '#000000'
    },
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    showDialog: true,
    openLocationServices: true,
    preventOutSideTouch: true,
    preventBackClick: true,
    providerListener: true
  }).then(function(success) {
    console.log(success)
    // return <AuthScreen/>
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
  };

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('locationProviderStatusChange', function(status) {
  console.log(status);
});
};

componentWillUnmount() {
  LocationServicesDialogBox.stopListener();
};

render() {
if(!this.state.nextScreen) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    </View>
  );
} else {
  return <AuthScreen/>
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to navigate, you can use the `.then()` callback in which you're already logging the `success` parameter. According to the [doc](https://github.com/webyonet/react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box), `success` is an object with the following structure:

```
{ 
    alreadyEnabled: false, 
    enabled: true, 
    status: "enabled"
}
```

You just need to check if `success.enabled` is `true` and if that's the case call `setState({ nextScreen : true });`

Edit: Here's the code, as requested:

```
// MyView.js
componentDidMount()
{
    this.checkOrRequestLocationPermission();
}

checkOrRequestLocationPermission()
{
    if (Platform.OS === 'android')
    {
        LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
            // Your config
            // ...
        })
        .then(result => {
            if (result.enabled)
            {
                this.setState({
                    nextScreen : true
                });
            }

            // The above could be replaced by this
            // this.setState({
            //     nextScreen : result.enabled
            // });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.warn('Error requesting location permission ' + error);
        });
    }
}

render() {
    if(!this.state.nextScreen) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container} />
        );
    } 

    else {
        return <AuthScreen/>
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry just newbie here, can u give me the exact code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to check your comment, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hey I tried to observe the react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box in the console, but when I trying to enable the gps the result is always disabled, i tried in many ways but the result is still disabled in the console log. I think this package is broken

Comment: And there is a warning says, "Error requesting location permission Error: disabled"

Comment: Have you checked `status` ?

Comment: Yes, but the return in the conso log is always disabled even the GPS is turned on

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the package then.